# What to do to restart glassfish in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, server, glassfish, restart

I never needed glassfish till now, so i don't know much about it.

*example: application for guessing an imaginary number; as soon as the number is guessed true, I want to restart application and do that again with the new one*

Is there any command in netbeans,to type in browser or anywhere to restart application, session...? I can't go with ctrl+r.

p.s.I heard that it's not needed to pay too much attention to the warnings when loading glassfish, because they can be ignored and everything work fine anyway, is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any command in netbeans,to type in browser or anywhere to
>   restart application, session...?

I'm not sure what you mean by *"restart...session"* but if you are referring to restarting Glassfish there is no keyboard shortcut, and I don't think it is possible to add one. However, there are at least four ways to restart a running Glassfish server in NetBeans:

In the browser:

- Open Glassfish's **Administration Console** (http://localhost:4848), select **server (Admin Server)** and click the **Restart** button:

  [image: restartConsole]

In NetBeans:

- In the **Services** panel select the **Glassfish Server** node under the **Servers** node, press *Shift-F10* (or right click) to open the context menu, and select the **Restart** menu entry.
- In the **Output** window click the green **Restart Server** icon:

  [image: restartServer1]
- In the **Output** window click the **GlassFish Server** tab, position the curson over the window, right-click and select **Restart** from the popup menu:

  [image: restartServer2]

To redeploy your application on the server after changing ****.java*** files, simply select the project node in the **Projects** panel, right-click and select **Deploy** from the popup menu.

You don't need to do anything at all after changing ****.html*** and ****.jsp*** files. The application server will detect the changes automatically.

> I heard that it's not needed to pay too much attention to the warnings
>   when loading glassfish, because they can be ignored and everything
>   work fine anyway, is that true?

Obviously that depends on the warning, but I am running Glassfish 5 with NetBeans and do not get any warnings when starting the server. So if you are seeing warning messages in your Glassfish log you should probably try to understand why they are there. They may or may not be serious.

Comment: Very helpful :) what about these warnings at the beginning: `WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI`.
`WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.` ; 
`WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/home/maxx/jdk1.8.0_171/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.` I can run web application but don't know is this bad